# What programmable board should I use for my project?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, diy, board

I have a small project going on, you can call this a research project that I needed to pass a certain class。 But the thing is, I don't know what I should use Arduino? Raspberry Pi? Im a complete beginner so please help me.

Here is my project:
I will make a device that does some web scraping stuff where it will collect necessary data on a site and for the collected data, there will be a certain condition where, if that data passes that condition, an action will occur like sending a SMS message or activate an alarm or something.

So I need help on where I should start and I'll probably handle the rest through the power of internet. I'll probably take care of the coding stuff. I need to know what electronics I should use and if it's possible, recommend a cheap and affordable one. Thanks

Comment: "Shopping" questions are off topic.  Given the web connectivity requirement, realistically you should start by getting a software solution running on the PC you posted this from.  Do that in python or another portable way (or if your PC already runs Linux) and then porting to something like a pi is straightforward.  But get it working first.  Sending an SMS is best done via an Internet based gateway service, if you need to control some local device there are things like USB relays, or at that point you could move to an embedded platform like a pi.  But **get the software working first**.

Comment: Assuming the software stuff is taken care of, would a pi be suited for the job?

Comment: A pi is absolutely fine, an arduino would work as well if you don't need too much ram and cpu power. There are lots of shields out there for whatever you like (SIM, sensors, ethernet, etc.) which are typically compatible with both arduino and raspberry pi.

Comment: No, an Arduino is really *not* suited to anything that requires interacting with web resources.  At best it can be done in a limited way with difficulty, but you'll struggle to implement things typically considered baseline necessities like SSL.  A pi is computationally suitable, though in terms of system state it may be a bit fragile compared to more purpose built embedded systems given the SD card dependence.